# A little help with this limit problem.

Tags: limits

[image]

I've been trying to solve this equation, but i just can't figure it out how it was solved in the text book. I am stuck, thought i should ask here.

I am **NOT** allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule!

The sulution based on the text book is: -5/3

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a problem that's constructed specifically to train L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention, i am NOT allowed to use L'Hospital's Rule, Sorry i'll edit that!

Comment: Are you allowed to **prove** a lemma that just happens to be L'Hospital's rule and _then_ use it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I imagine not, but nice try :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the numerator, each root separately has the value 2 at x=1. Now consider the limit of

$$r_1(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-2}{x-1}$$

at $x=1$ using the binomial formulas and then insert $\sqrt{x+3}=2+(x-1)r_1(x)$ into the big limit. Analogous results using geometric sums apply to the other root expressions.